# Entity Framework query missing a filtered index on SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, prepared-statement, filtered-index

I have this EF query: (only kept the essential part)

```
int maxRetryCount = 5;
var erroredArchiveFilesQuery =
  transitionLogSessionContext.Set<ArchivedFile>().Where(f => 
  f.RetryCount < maxRetryCount
).Take(maxBatchSize);
```

It misses the filtered index available.

Whereas when removing the variable `maxRetryCount` as such

```
var erroredArchiveFilesQuery =
transitionLogSessionContext.Set<ArchivedFile>().Where(f => 
f.RetryCount < 5 && 
).Take(maxBatchSize);
```

will use the filtered index.

The actual SQL from the first EF query...

```
SELECT TOP (500) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
     ..
FROM  
    [ArchivedFile] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 
    ([Extent1].[RetryCount] < @p__linq__0 )
```

The filtered index contains the column `RetryCount` and a filter 'RetryCount < 5'

How can I make an ef query with a variable that will hit filtered index?

I assume the problem is in the EF statement being prepared so it can be reused, and this confuses the SQL Server.

Comment: you should clarify your code. Your code ist not valid (does not compile). Also make sure you mark all your code sections as code.

Comment: I had problems getting the middle code section shown as code, but rewriting it helped. I didn't intend for the code to be able to compile, but hopefully all the essential parts are there. If the problem does not make sense now, just let me know where I should clearify. Thanks

Comment: .Where(f => f.RetryCount < 5 && )
What should this piece of code do?

Comment: Please can you show your table & filtered index definition

Comment: I suspect that this is due to your queryplan being generated for all cases of @p_linq_0 which could be any value, therefore a plan that uses the filtered index will not always be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that SQL Server recompiles the plan each time based upon the actual value of the parameter `maxRetryCount`. This is not easy in EF but can be done using a custom database interceptor to add `option (recompile)` hint to your query.

See details here [SimpleTalk Article](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-tools/entity-framework-performance-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/)

```
public class RecompileDbCommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command,  DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        if(!command.CommandText.EndsWith(" option(recompile)"))
        {
            command.CommandText +=  " option(recompile)";
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var interceptor = new RecompileDbCommandInterceptor();
DbInterception.Add(interceptor);

int maxRetryCount = 5;
var erroredArchiveFilesQuery =
  transitionLogSessionContext.Set<ArchivedFile>().Where(f => 
  f.RetryCount < maxRetryCount
).Take(maxBatchSize);

DbInterception.Remove(interceptor);
```

Note that this interception is enabled globally, not for the specific instance of the context, so you probably want to disable it again so that other queries aren’t affected.